# Grails one-to-many relationship data binding

Tags: grails, many-to-many

I am new to Grails and am trying to test a sample one-to-many form as outlined in the link below

http://www.2paths.com/2009/10/01/one-to-many-relationships-in-grails-forms/

The views seem to be working fine as I can add new text field for Book (child) from Parent (Author) and delete as necessary.
However, the databinding for child data (Books) doesn't seem to be working. 
Books that belong to the Author are not added to the database when I add them in the view.
It was my understanding that the default controller should work in this case. Am I wrong on that?
Do I have to modify the save() method for the AuthorController?

I see that the above post was from 2010 and I am currently using Grails 2.4.2.
Could that be the issue?